# Big Sur unified toolbar -- how to ... NSWindow/NSToolbar

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, appkit, macos-big-sur, nstoolbar

How can I detect that NSWindow/NSToolbar is using an unified toolbar with the windowtitle in the toolbar ?

(true if bigsur running, Titlebar height of window ?)  -- no good idea !

Most of all I would continue the catalina look with a windowtitlebar !

if I do [ window setWindowVisibility: NSWindowTileHidden ] I get a toolbar a bit cramped without windowtitle and text on the toolbar items.

anyone got some ideas ?

Software compiled under Catalina continues to keep their Catalina look running under BigSur, so on X86 I just can continue compiling on Catalina for a while !

But with ARM64 (aka m1) I have to fight the unified toolbar :)

/Alexis

Answer (score 1):

Solved

[ window setToolbarStyle: NSWindowToolbarStyleExpanded ];

seem to fix it :)

/Alexis